# steps to deploy angular application and .net core web api

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, web-deployment

I have a separate angular application and .net core web api. I want to deploy both angular and web api as a bundle in IIS. On My localhost, I am running my angular application by putting the URL of the web api in my angular application. This is what I have in my angular application:

```
export const ROOT_URL=   'https://localhost:44312/api/RecloadPrime';
```

This is how I am calling my api from my angular application:

```
UploadRecLoadData(recLoaddata: RecLoadDataTypeModel){

 return  this.http.get<string>(ROOT_URL + '/' + recLoaddata.startDate +'/' + recLoaddata.endDate , {responseType: 'text' as 'json'});
}
```

Both the angular and web API works fine. I tested everything on my localhost. My .net core version is 2.2

can someone tell me the steps to deploy the applications to IIS.

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new Website in IIS or use default website
2. Add Application to the website and in that put your webapi
3. Now add a Virtual directory and put ur website in that

i am not including how to put up application pool and other aspects here 
at the end you will get something like this

[image]

please dont mind aspnet_client folder

Comment: what about my angular part of the application. Like, I mentioned in my question that I want to deploy both angular and .net core web api. How will I integrate them together